# Why does HttpClient.PostAsync not throw on failure?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an ASP.Net Core web service if an HttpClient.GetStringAsync call fails for 404 error or whatever, it throws an HttpRequestException. This is great.

If on the other hand an HttpClient.PostAsync call fails for 404, it does not throw an exception. I have to check the status code, fabricate an exception and throw it manually.

Why the discrepency, and is there a more elegant way of dealing with this?

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await _http.PostAsync("api/pollapi/request", new StringContent(requestInput));

if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   throw new HttpRequestException($"Response status does not indicate success: {(int)response.StatusCode} ({response.StatusCode}).");
}
```

Comment: You can use [`HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Perfect. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Note that the analogous method to `PostAsync` would be `GetAsync`, not `GetStringAsync`. The latter does *more* than just sending a request and obtaining a response - it also attempts to process the response body and turn it into a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx) method that:

> Throws an exception if the IsSuccessStatusCode property for the HTTP response is false.

Comment: Sometimes things were just designed with Vexing behavior, but later got a less-Vexing alternative. Parse is anotorious example of such a Vexing behavior. Wich is why TryParse was added in 2.0

Comment: This doesn't answer the "Why the discrepency?" part, which is that `PostAsync`'s job is to do an HTTP POST and one might reasonably want to handle an error at the HTTP level in some way other than through exceptions, but `GetStringAsync`'s job is to do an HTTP GET and **then** get the string contents of the successful web request, a combined operation for which there's no meaningful non-exceptional way to handle HTTP errors like there might be at a slightly lower level.

Comment: Good point. In my particular case though I just wanted my PostAsync to throw the same kind of exception as all my get calls without having to create it manually, and this achieves that.

Comment: It works, but I was disapointed that the exception thrown by this method does not let see the response of the failed request. So I chose to reconstruct and rethrow the exception manually anyway.